# Can exim delay emails after a defined limit is reached?

Tags: email, exim, email-server

In a vps I am limited by a certain number of sent emails per minute (they say it's a way to control spam!), I could use a relay server but I don't want!

Probably I will never reach the limit, but just in case, can I define a limit to exim and delay the emails a certain time if the limit is reached?

Comment: Your VPS provider has no business knowing numbers or interfering with SMTP. Find a new provider.

Comment: Please tell us what VPS provider this is so we know who to avoid.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz http://wiki.lusovps.com/index.php/Relay

Comment: Oh, they *provide* a relay server for you? Why don't you just use it? Trust me, you don't want the administrative nightmare of running a mail server if someone else is offering to do it for you.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz At least now I am not afraid of that! To use the relay I need to configure all the stuff in the same way and some more dns entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ratelimit submission to Exim, using ACL `ratelimit` rules.  It doesn't directly control outbound rate and won't let you smooth out any bursts.  You might use it to not actually limit but to log the events and send you a non-email-based alert if you start getting near to the limit.